# How do I find a cont. non-vanishing vector field on $\Bbb S^n$, $n=$odd, such that there exists a Lorentz metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I know that the Hairy ball theorem plus the following proposition

**Proposition**
For a smooth manifold $M$.

There exists a Lorentz metric on $M$ $\iff$ there is a continuous non-vanishing vector field on $M$

allow one to conclude that there is no Lorenzian metric on even dimensional n-spheres.

**I would like to find a continuous non-vanishing vector field on $M$ so that (hopefully) applying the proposition I could conclude that there exists a Lorentz metric in odd dimensional n-spheres  How do I do that?**

Comment: Consider $S^n$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as the unit sphere. For a point on the unit sphere $(x_1,y_1,\ldots, x_n, y_n)$ the vector $(y_1,-x_1, \dots, y_n, -x_n)$ is a unit tangent vector at that point. These give you a smooth nonvanishing vector field.

Comment: @jgon Thanks for the anwer, Isn't by definition the n-sphere embedded in $ \Bbb R^{n+1}$ so why going to $ \Bbb R^{2n}$ and how do I see that that vector is a unit vector? For example for n=3 , the equation of the sphere is $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$ and the Lorentz metric by defintion has signature (-,+....,+)so I guess the norm square of the vector is computed as $-y_1^2+(-x_1)^2+(y_2)^2+(-x_2)^2+(y_3)^2+(-x_3)^2$, which does not seem to symplify to 1 plus I don't see how the chosen signs are then useful. Sorry I am just getting started with these concepts

Comment: @some_math_guy This was presumably a typo. If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even, and the construction above works. In addition, you are not a priori given any Lorentzian metric, but you should build one out of the vector field that was given to you.

Comment: @Didier What would the typo be? The given vector field clearly has 2n components. I don't see how this works if I change 2n to n+1 if that is what you meant, then the vector would have 2(n+1) coordinates

Comment: The typo is: It should be $S^{2n-1}$ embedded as the unit sphere in $R^{2n}$.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan
Ok, but I still don't see why$ (y_1,-x_1,...y_n,-x_n)$ is a tangent unit vector.  The equation of the sphere is $x_1^2+....x_n^2+y_1^2+....+y_n^2=1$ and with a Lorenzian metric it means the signature is (-++...+)so a squared norm of a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,....v_{2n})$is computed as $||v||^2=-v_1^2+v_2^2+.....v_{2n}^2$ If I apply this to$(y_1,-x_1,...y_n,-x_n)$. I don't see how that is 1 or why it is usefull to define it with those (-) signs if they are going to be squared anyway

Comment: No, if you want to prove tangency,  the metric to use is Euclidean, not Lorentz. The proof of tangency is then immediate.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ahh,ok now it makes sense. The inner product with Euclidean metric of the point and the vector field gives 0, the squared norm of the vector is equal to one side of the equation of the sphere so it is 1, and how do I justify continuity of the vector field?

Comment: I assume you took a vector calculus class at some point. Did you verify continuity of any function in that class, such as a linear function?

Comment: Mostly used that all components of the vector function is continuous iff the vector function is continuous, but that yields a continuos function on $R^{2n}$ If I want to restrict it to the manifold will it stay continuous no matter how "ugly" the embedded manifold could be?

Comment: I think you would really benefit from tak8ng a real analysis class or reading a real analysis book on your own, otherwise you will be always stuck on such issues. The thing is, the restriction of a continuous function to **any** subset is again continuous.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thought the given vector field work for any n odd, but I found in Barrett O'Neill's - Semi-Riemannian Geometry  book that a  a sphere S"  admits a Lorentz
metric if and only if n is odd $\ge 3.$, so i wonder what is wrong with the case n=1? It looks to me that the tangent vector $(y_1,-x_1)$ for a point $(x_1,y_1)$ in the 1-sphere also work just as fine

Comment: I think he does not regard 1-dimensional manifolds as Lorentzian since the metric there is definite.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Does it matter that the given vector field has norm=1 in this example?

Comment: It is totally irrelevant. The important part is that the vector is nonzero. This is what allows one to define a Lirentzian metric on a manifold.